# Including .o files in Cython Project

Tags: python-3.x, cython, cythonize

I am trying to make Python bindings to interact with a C object, using Cython. I was given:

`parser.o` and `parser.h`

I've made my `.pyx` and `.pxd` files to define the methods and types that I'll use from the `.h` file. When I try to call a method that I defined in my `.pxd` that mirrors one defined in the `.h`, I get the error:

`undefined symbol: function_name`

My setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
        Extension(
                'parser',
                ['parser.pyx'],
        )
]
compiler_directives = {'language_level': 3}

setup(
        ext_modules = cythonize(
                extensions,
                **compiler_directives
        )
)
```

I think I don't know how to include the `parser.o` files I was given. Any help on how to link the `.o` file with what I'm trying to do would be great.

Comment: Did you figure out a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered the same problem this morning, and found that the extension needs the additional .o files to be provided through `extra_link_args`.  However, in your case, I have some concern that Cython will clobber your `parser.c` file.  It might help to rename the original `parser.c` and `parser.h` to something like `parser_c.c` and `parser_c.h` to avoid this; and generate `parser_c.o`.

````
from Cython.Build import cythonize

extensions = [
        Extension(
                'parser',
                ['parser.pyx'],
                extra_link_args = ['parser_c.o']
        )
]
compiler_directives = {'language_level': 3}

setup(
        ext_modules = cythonize(
                extensions,
                **compiler_directives
        )
)```
````

Comment: For object files, there is a special option in `Extension`-class: `extra_objects`, see https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.Extension